# SQLite software to use db with iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Hi i'm starting to test data persistance for iOS and i want to use some databases, i tried few project with the command line but i would love to start using a software that will speed up the process.

I read already a post on here where an user listed few software from a website.

Here i copy the link he shared, 
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools
i would love to know if any of you tested those software, and which one you raccomand.

On many books i read they use a firefox plugin, but i find firefox already too slow to add such a powerful plugin.

Please if you find this question stupid, don't flag or downvote. I looked for a similar topic and i didn't find the answer i wanted. Thank you

Comment: Also look at Apple's Core Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used SQLite Database Browser. It's free, easy to use and gets the job done.

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have used Base: available on the MAC App Store:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base/id402383384?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

I've used Arango Db. It's free http://www.arangodb.org